# Resource request: linear logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, linear-logic

Is there any correct book/textbook/pdf to understand what is linear logic ? I do research in (standard) logic/model theory, so I'm totally ok with a text which assumes mathematical maturity.

Comment: See e.g.Jean-Yves Girard, [Linear logic](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397587900454) Theoretical Computer Science (1987) as well as Anne Troelstra, [Lectures on Linear Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=DSVcPwAACAAJ) CSLI (1992).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure there's a good reference at the moment. I guess Girard's *The Blind Spot* is a book mostly about linear logic but it's very polarizing and sometimes offensive (though I personally learned a lot from it). In a few years though the Handbook of Linear Logic should be done; there's an [early draft](https://ll-handbook.frama.io/ll-handbook/ll-handbook-li2022.pdf) that was used at the [Linear Logic 2022 Winter School](https://conferences.cirm-math.fr/2685.html) whose lectures were recorded.